# Respond to the action bar's Up button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am using `android-support-v7-appcompat` library.

In my fragment I have a custom action bar with different controls. onclick of button, I change the drawer hamburger icon to back button.

Code :

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Now I have a back button displaying on the screen. When I click on the back button nothing happens.

I tried this in my fragment :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            Log.i("Back Button ", "back button clicked ");
            return true;
        default: 
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

But still nothing works.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you click on the back button?

Comment: i just what to detect the click and do some action on that

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to capture back button event.

Also add following two lines:

and add one custom layout for your action bar in which back button and title 
will be there.You can override back button click event from your custom layout.

You can set custom view to your action bar like below:

mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);

mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: What is the difference in my code snippet and yours ? i have already done the same thing

Comment: Yes i am using custom view along with that i  am using the action bar back button so is that the reason i am not able to detect the click ?

Comment: You mean if i use the custom view then i also need to add custom back button and not the action bar back button ?

Comment: Yes these two lines will work for you.

mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

Comment: No i meant do i need to use the custom back button ? for my custom layout action bar ? can i not use the action bar back button ?

Comment: Yes you should put one imageview or button with back arrow and override its click event from your custom view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76887/discussion-between-user2056563-and-jay-shah).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out... In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, find the activity related to your fragment, add the property `android:parentActivityName` and set a parent activity. Then, remove the lines

```
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: as i had said its not activity and its fragment